# definition Stone for Pah Tum play

Tags: python

I have to write a programm about the Pah tun and i am an amateur programmer.

Colud you please tell me how can I write two Stone black and white.

```
def stein(number,faces,seed):
    i = 1

    ausgabe =""

    delta_faces = 1/faces 

    while i <= number:

         # eingabe von seed damit der zufallgenerator wirklich als ZufÃ¤llig ist
        random.seed(seed)

        # hier wird eine zufällige float Zahl zwischen 0-1 bestimmt
        wurfZahl=random.random() 

        # Bei dieser If schleife wird der Fall gedeckt
        # wo der 
        if(wurfZahl%delta_faces==0):   
            ausgabe=ausgabe+str(int(wurfZahl//delta_faces))

        elif(wurfZahl%delta_faces!=0):
            ausgabe=ausgabe+str(int((wurfZahl//delta_faces)+1))

        # Hier wird i auf addiert damit der schleife spÃ¤ter abbricht.        
        i=i+1 

    return ausgabe
```

this is what I defined for that. but it doesnt work currectly.

Thank you

Comment: You should probably describe your problem in more details. What are you trying to do? What do you expect to happen? What have you tried? And you shouldn't expect people here to be able to understand german.

Comment: I tried to find something about this pah tun game, but Google doesn't come up with anything useful. Do you have a link to the rules, so people understand, what you are trying to achieve? Please add information about expected behaviour and how your program behaves differently from that.

Comment: of course. that was just some definition for myself. Sorry!!

http://self.gutenberg.org/articles/Pah_Tum This link helps to understand the gamerules.
Actually I defined the board as 7*7 Matrix.   
My problem is now how can I define the black and white stone, which randomly on of the field of board blocked.
 
Hopefully Its better now :) 
Thank you

Comment: I am afraid, it is still not clear, what your function is supposed to do. What do `number`, `faces` and `ausgabe` represent? You use a random function in it - is it to randomly assign the black holes on the board? Or is it to place one of the black and white stones - then the question arises, why this happens randomly and not with a strategy. Which party is the computer and which is the player? You have to give more context, otherwise people can't help you.